# 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 81: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python

I am trying to send the following JSON object to a webservice api and ran into Error1 below,then I added `.encode("utf-8").strip()` to the title(see code snippet) below and then ran to Error1,now am lost as to how to fix this?any one provide pointers?

```
{"component":{"name":"comp chip PCIe", "version":"X"},"assignee":123449612,"milestone":"Internal Tools - Mile","priority":2,"state":"Analyze","substate":"Nominate","title":"[Cloning for automation checkin]SVT:UDM:4364B2::SITM: Observing few instances of “CW Firmware Requested Dump PCIe~reason=(0x6)” followed by “watchdog@CW Chip Trap~Type=4,PC=0x1666F0,LR=0xEEEEEEEE” during SITM test."}
```

Code Snippet:

```
title = "[" + sys.argv[5] +"]" +  orgRadar['title'].encode("utf-8").strip()
```

Error1:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 253: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Error2:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 81: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you use Python 2.x. You can use 3.x instead, your code will work fine without encode required.

For 2.x, refer to [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). For short, you can replace every `'your string'` with `u'your string'`.

Comment: I tried as `title = "[" + sys.argv[5] +"]" + unicode(orgRadar['title'])` but didnt work ,can you please be more specific in my case?